# Прокручивать страницу при сколее карты (событиях drag)

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

На мобильных устройствах карта может занимать весь экран. При этом невозможно прокрутить страницу вверх или вниз. Можно отключить поведение scrollZoom и drag. При этом карта не будет прокручиваться внутри своего контейнера, но и страница остаётся на месте. Видимо событие "не доходит" до страницы.

Хочется сохранить возможность взаимодействия с картой посредство multiTouch и кнопочек, поэтому не хочется заменять динамическую карту на картинку.

Есть ли возможность передавать события drag странице, при этом оставляя возможность масштабировать карту мультитачем и нажимать на имеющиеся кнопки управления.

Comment: Достаточно отключить драг и всё работает map.behaviors.disable(['drag']); Пример: alyniekka.com/se0ga/drag.html

Comment: Благодарю за ответ @se0ga. По указанной Вами ссылке карта во весь экран. Проверить скролл основной страницы невозможно. Думаю, Вы не до конца поняли вопрос (или я плохо объяснил). Мне нужно, чтобы при драге на карте сама карта в контейнере не прокруручивалась бы, а страница, на которой расположен контейнер с картой - прокручивалась.

Comment: Да, там карта на весь экран, но драг на мобильном работает так как под картой есть пустой блок. Вы же имеете ввиду драг страницы на мобильном устройстве одним пальцем? Или скролл страницы в десктопном браузере с помощью колёсика мыши?

Comment: Я имею в виду прокручивание страницы (не карты внутри контейнера) одним пальцем. В Вашем примере на мобильном Chrome "драг" работает только в том случае, если попасть на один из элементов управления (типа ссылки на Яндекс или кнопки +/-). При "драге" на основной площади карты драг не работает. А это именно то, что мне требуется реализовать.

Comment: Попробуйте сейчас alyniekka.com/se0ga/drag.html . Судя по всему в одной из версий Яндекс что-то изменил и теперь не работает пример. Зафиксировал предыдущую версию и пример начал работать. В Яндекс я написал, чтобы они починили это. Вы в свою очередь тоже им напишите для того, чтобы нас было больше)